# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:paddingBottom="25sp"
    android:paddingLeft="5sp"
    android:paddingRight="5sp"
    android:paddingTop="25sp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/mainlogo"
            android:id="@+id/ClickHereToEnter"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:gravity="center">

        </ImageView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lunch"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:textColor="#90A4AE"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

*This error appears to me and I don't know why?? and can't solve it any help, please?
        when run application this error appear to me and detected error in java page in line 17 
       (setContentView(R.layout.activity_main))!!! so can anyone help me?*

Comment: where is line 37 ?

Comment: where is your java file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon you may be using Toolbar of support library and having dependencies of androidx.Check your dependency in build.gradle whether it is androidX or support library and accordingly use that Toolbar in your xml layout file.

Comment: yes, i checked dependency in build.gradle and support library and accordingly use that Toolbar in your xml layout file.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add to your XML file , I hope it will help you .

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/black" />
```